iText 8 - PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE not getting fired
It looks like PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE is not getting fired all the times as expected. The code below will generate C:\temp\pageEvent.pdf, and if you look at page 5 or page 9, they have new page, and header is the first line on the new page, and I want zero top-padding there.
package com.falconjet.molp;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.Event;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.IEventHandler;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.PdfDocumentEvent;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.Border;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.UnitValue;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class PageEventDemo {
    public void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("C:\\temp\\pageEvent.pdf");
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        NewPageEventHandler newPageEventHandler = new NewPageEventHandler();
        pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, newPageEventHandler);
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        document.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);
        Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPointArray(new float[]{100}));
        table.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
        for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
            if(i % 5 == 0) {
                float topPadding = newPageEventHandler.getNoTopPadding() ? 0 : 15f;
                Cell cell = new Cell()
                        .setPaddingTop(topPadding)
                        .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
                        .setBold()
                        .add(new Paragraph("Header"));
                table.addCell(cell);
            } else if (i % 2 == 0) {
                Cell cell = new Cell()
                        .setPaddingTop(0)
                        .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
                        .add(new Paragraph("Small data cell"));
                table.addCell(cell);
            } else {
                Cell cell = new Cell()
                        .setPaddingTop(0)
                        .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
                        .add(new Paragraph("Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell Long data cell "));
                table.addCell(cell);
            }
        }
        document.add(table);
        pdf.close();
    }
    class NewPageEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
        boolean noTopPadding;
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            //No top padding if header is the first line on a new page
            noTopPadding = true;
        }
        boolean getNoTopPadding() {
            return noTopPadding;
        }
    }
}



Obviously the page events are not triggered while you add the cells to the table; at that time no pages are started or finished. The page events are triggered when you add the table to the document.

Is there a way to achieve the desired result ? When a new page starts, I do not want any top padding on the header, but subsequent headers which could be on the same page needs top padding.

Well, There surely is a way to get that result but I'm not sure there is an easy one. Merely a page event listener won't do for the reason given above. Unfortunately, though, I'm not really into the fine tuning of layout generation, so I don't know how to do it correctly.
